# AttributeError: instance has no attribute, within __init__

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, attributeerror, bitcoin, linux-mint

I can't seem to figure out where the problem is,

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./miningScreensaver", line 171, in <module>
    miningScreensaver().loop.run()
  File "./miningScreensaver", line 81, in __init__
    self.rxAddress = self.getRxAddress
AttributeError: miningScreensaver instance has no attribute 'getRxAddress'
```

code:

```
#! Python
class miningScreensaver:
    def __init__(self):
        DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
        self.mem='ActiveChanged'
        self.dest='org.gnome.ScreenSaver'
        self.bus=SessionBus()
        self.loop=MainLoop()
        self.bus.add_signal_receiver(self.catch,self.mem,self.dest)
        self.pipe = ""

        #if you would like to specify a different rx address
        # change rxAddress to the desired rx address 
        self.rxAddress = self.getRxAddress()   #<--------------------ERROR HERE line 81
        #self.rxaddress = "18X3TEigc6PVTsF9Atx5br7rEXfuZRqXEz"

    def catch(self,ssOn):
        if ssOn == 1: #Screensaver turned on
            self.start()
        else: #Screensaver turned off
            self.stop()

    def start(self):
        self.pipe = Popen(["cgminer -o stratum+tcp://stratum.mining.eligius.st:3334 -u " + self.rxAddress + " -p x -I 9"], shell=True)

    def stop(self):
        self.pipe.kill()

    def getRxAddress(self):
        #check if bitcoin.conf exists
        cmd = "ls $HOME/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf"
        pipe = Popen(cmd,stdout=PIPE,stderr=STDOUT)
        pout = pipe.stdout.read()
        pout = pout.split()
        if pout[len(pout)-5]=='No' and \
          pout[len(pout)-4]=='such' and \
          pout[len(pout)-3]=='file' and \
          pout[len(pout)-2]=='or' and \
          pout[len(pout)-1]=='directory\n':
            password = self.createBitConf()      
        else: 
            #check password 
            password = self.checkPassword()

        #Launch bitcoin-qt -server
        Popen(["bitcoin-qt","-server"])
        #Access
        access = ServiceProxy("http://darkPenguin:"+password+"@127.0.0.1:8332")
        #access.getinfo()
        return access.listreceivedbyaddress(0)
        #access.sendtoaddress("12yBwyDJHABCvohdT8qBTeMJEYDqpXnVYV", 0.01)

    def createBitConf(self):
        randomPW = self.createRandomPW()
        path = expanduser("~") + "/"
        defFile = open("bitosbitcoinconf", "r")
        newFile = open(path + ".bitcoin/bitcoin.conf","w")
        for line in range(1,55):
            newFile.write(defFile.readline())
        password = "rpcpassword="+randomPW+"\n"
        for line in range(56,110):
            newFile.write(defFile.readline())
        defFile.close()
        newFile.close()
        return randomPW

    def createRandomPW(self):
        myrg = random.SystemRandom()
        length = 44
        alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
        pw = str().join(myrg.choice(alphabet) for _ in range(length))
        return pw

    def checkPassword(self):
        path = expanduser("~") + "/"
        bitConfFile = open(path + ".bitcoin/bitcoin.conf","r")
        password = bitConfFile.readline(56)
        bitConfFile.close()
        return password[12:12+44-1] # "rpcpassword="+randomPW+"\n"

miningScreensaver().loop.run()
```

This is driving me batty, both the method call and method are spelled exactly the same and solutions to other peoples problems have been no help.

Comment: Your error does not match your code. Did you change your code since you got that error? Rerun it and see what happens. (Also, it's highly recommended that any classes that don't inherit from anything instead inherit from `object`. Otherwise, you'll get old-style classes, which suck.)

Comment: As a completely-unrelated-to-your-problem side note, doing a `Popen` to an `ls` command and parsing the error message has to be the most convoluted way I've ever seen to verify that a file exists…

Comment: Check your indentation? The `getRxAddress` might be dedented so that it's a function defined after the class, rather than a method.

Comment: Another thing: Why are you using `#! Python` as your shbang line on linux? That can't be a useful interpreter path…

Comment: LMFAO at abarnert, thanks man. it made perfect sense at the time, well I am getting this error, just check for this error instead of googling how to check if a file exists in python, which I should know.

Comment: Also abarnert I was seeing if the '#! Python' would add Python syntax highlighting for Python to Stackoverflow, which I don't know, maybe it is the tag

Comment: @user2237853: To check if a file exists, just use `os.path.exists`, or `os.stat`. But more often than not, you want to open the file if it exists, in which case… don't check it, just `try` to open it, and deal with a file not found error appropriately.

Comment: Anyway it was mixing tabs and spaces, got an indent error after making getRxAddress a local function in __init__, and I removed a lot of comments when pasting the code here. see https://sourceforge.net/p/bit-os/code/ci/master/tree/

Comment: @abarnert your right the try except block is much cleaner, thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mixed tabs and spaces. Set your editor to show whitespace, and you'll see the problem. Running python with the `-tt` option can help.

Answer (score 2):

A quick check with the Edit button shows that you're mixing tabs and spaces.

In particular, the first few methods of `miningScreensaver` are indented by a bunch of spaces, while the rest—including getRxAddress—are indented by a tab. So, Python considers those methods to be dedented outside of the class, meaning they're compiled as top-level functions, not methods of `miningScreensaver` instances.

To fix this, untabify your code and manually clean up the indentation.

To avoid this in the future, use a better text editor, and run Python with the `-t` or `-tt` flag so it'll give you an obvious error about inconsistent tab/space usage instead of trying to parse the code and giving you an error you can't understand.